# Python regex: how to achieve this complex replacement rule?

Tags: python, regex, re-python

I'm working with long strings and I need to replace with `''` all the combinations of adjacent full stops `.` and/or colons `:`, but only when they are not adjacent to any whitespace. Examples:

- `a.bcd` should give `abcd`
- `a..::.:::.:bcde.....:fg` should give `abcdefg`
- `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h` should give `abcdefgh`
- `a .b` should give `a .b`, because `.` here is adjacent to a whitespace on its left, so it has not to be replaced
- `a..::.:::.:bcde.. ...:fg` should give `abcde.. ...:fg` for the same reason

Well, here is what I tried (without any success).

**Attempt 1:**

```
s1 = r'a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h'
re.sub(re.search(r'[^\s.:]+([.:]+)[^\s.:]+', s1).group(1), r'', s1)
```

I would expect to get `'abcdefgh'` but what I actually get is `r''`. I understood why: the code

```
re.search(r'[^\s.:]+([.:]+)[^\s.:]+', s1).group(1)
```

returns `'.'` instead of `'\.'`, and thus `re.search` doesn't understand that it has to replace the single full stop `.` rather than understanding `'.'` as the usual regex.

**Attempt 2:**

```
s1 = r'a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h'
re.sub(r'([^\s.:]*\S)[.:]+(\S[^\s.:]*)', r'\g<1>\g<2>', s1)
```

This doesn't work as it returns `a.b.c.d.e.f.gh`.

**Attempt 3:**

```
s1 = r'a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h'
re.sub(r'([^\s.:]*)[.:]+([^\s.:]*)', r'\g<1>\g<2>', s1)
```

This works on `s1`, but it doesn't solve my problem because on `s2 = r'a .b'` it returns `a b` rather than `a .b`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Remember that a backslash is special both in strings and in regular expressions, so you need to escape it properly.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<![\s.])\.(?![\s.])', '', s)`

Comment: `re.sub('\\\.', '', s1)` should suffice

Comment: Note that you don't need to escape `.` inside a character class.

Comment: I can't simply do `re.sub('\\\.', '', s1)`, I updated the question in order to explain why. Many thanks and sorry.

Comment: @AvinashRaj your solution doesn't solve my problem. If I understand well, my problem is that `re.search` returns `'.'`, which without the backslash means to substitute each character, digit, symbol, etc. I rather need to substitute only the points, so I need `re.search` to return something like `\.`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using the backslash exactly because it is special: the point `.` alone would mean to match anything, whereas I need to match points only. So, for all I know, I need to use the backslash `\.` in order to specify this.

Comment: Your exposition is riddled by mixing these notations. The *regular expression* `r'\.'` can only match and return the *string* `'.'`. There is no `'\.'` anywhere in `s1` so it is completely impossible that any regular expression could find and return that.

Comment: I got the point here, the string `\.` doesn't occur in `s1`; only `.` does. What I can't figure out is how to make `re.sub` to replace the point only, without interpreting `.` in the usual sense of regexs. I mean, if I write `re.sub('.', '', s1)` it's obvious that it would have to replace anything with `''`, but I would like to tell it something like "replace `\.`, not `.`". But it seems like this is not possible... if I understand well, to me this looks like a missing feature. I mean, it's completely natural to request something like "find a point and replace it with something else".

Comment: `re.sub(r'\.', '', s1)` does what you are asking, in isolation; it replaces a literal dot with nothing.  Equivalently, you could say `re.sub(r'[.]', '', s1)`

Comment: @tripleee of course, this way is trivial. But I need to use a more complex regex in order to achieve the generality I need. See below, under your answer.

Comment: Just to inform that I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.  Your regex doesn't match what you want to match; but also, your understanding of `re.sub` and `re.search` is off.

To find something, `re.search` lets you find where in a string that something occurs.

To *replace* that something, use `re.sub` on the same regular expression *instead of* `re.search`, not as well.

And, understand that `re.sub(r'thing(moo)other', '', s1)` replaces *the entire match*  with the replacement string.

With that out of the way, for your regex, it sounds like you want

```
r'(?<![\s.:])[.:]+(?![\s.:])'   # updated from comments, thanks!
```

which contains a character class with full stop and colon (notice how no backslash is necessary inside the square brackets -- this is a context where dot and colon do not have any special meaning<sup>1</sup>), repeated as many times as possible; and lookarounds on both sides to say we cannot match these characters when there is whitespace `\s` on either side, and also excluding the characters themselves so that there is no way for the regex engine to find a match by applying the `+` less strictly (it will do its darndest to find a match if there is a way).

Now, the regex only matches the part you want to actually replace, so you can do

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = 'name.surname@domain.com'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<![\s.:])[.:]+(?![\s.:])', r'', s1)
'namesurname@domaincom'
```

though in the broader scheme of things, you also need to know how to preserve some parts of the match. For the purpose of this demonstration, I will use a regular expression which captures into parenthesized groups the text before and after the dot or colon:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.*\S)[.:]+(\S.*)', r'\g<1>\g<2>', s1)
'name.surname@domaincom'
```

See how `\g<1>` in the replacement string refers back to "whatever the first set of parentheses matched" and similarly `\g<2>` to the second parenthesized group.

You will also notice that this failed to replace the first full stop, because the `.*` inside the first set of parentheses matches as much of the string as possible.  To avoid this, you need a regex which only matches as little as possible.  We already solved that above with the lookarounds, so I will leave you here, though it would be interesting (and yet not too hard) to solve this in a different way.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could even say that the normal regex language (or syntax, or notation, or formalism) is separate from the language (or syntax, or notation, or formalism) inside square brackets!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, there are a lot of things I wasn't aware of. Still it isn't clear to me how `\g<1>\g<2>` works. I tried with `s2 = a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h` and `re.sub(r'(.*\S)[.:]+(\S.*)', r'\g<1>\g<2>', s2)` returns `a.b.c.d.e.f.gh`, as I expected based on what you said, but `re.sub(r'([^\s.:]*\S)[.:]+(\S[^\s.:]*)', r'\g<1>\g<2>', s2)` returns a very strange `ab.cd.ef.gh`, whereas I expected `abcdefgh`. Why does it neglect the even occurrences of `.`? I read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) but I found nothing useful here.

Comment: Your regex always matches at least three characters; after a successful match and substitution, the next matching attempt starts imrediately after the text you have already matched.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know it reasons this way :( now I'm going to figure out how to fix this. No idea at the moment, I'll let you know asap. Thank you

Comment: It's not hard, `r'([^\s.:]*)[.:]+([^\s.:]*)'` without the `\S` inside the parentheses should do what you hope.

Comment: No, this doesn't yield what I would like to achieve. I immediately drop this solution because it removes `.` even when it confines with a white space. That is, it works fine with `a.b` yielding `ab`, but it fails with `a .b` as it gives `a b`, whereas I would like `a .b`. I have to remove `.` and `:` only when they are not adjacent to any white space. This is why I have no idea at the moment, and this is why I am still shocked how `re.sub` works with matches of groups.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand where you are stuck. Perhaps you want to accept this answer and post a new question with more details; or maybe [edit] your question and ping me, and I'll try to update my answer. (I think the former is better, though.)

Comment: I updated the question as the previous one was no longer significant. I hope the question looks clearer now.

Comment: @VanniRovera It's a lot clearer now but I don't understand why the lookarounds I proposed as my actual answer are not working, or did you not try that?

Comment: ...I totally forgot this one. It's close to perfection, nonetheless it fails with `a..::.:::.:bcde.. ...:fg`: this yields `abcde. .fg` rather than `abcde.. ...:fg` (see the question). So I used `r'(?<![\s.:])[.:]+(?![\s.:])'` instead and this worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I just suggest you to include this modified version in your answer, so that anyone can see the right solution.